# PostgreSQL DROP COLUMN: Remove One or More Columns of a Table

Tags: postgresql

To drop a column of a table, you use the DROP COLUMN clause in the ALTER TABLE statement as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE res_partner rs 
DROP COLUMN rs.miss_schedule;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "rs"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE res_partner rs

Comment: "not working" is not a valid Postgres error message. The syntax most definitely works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4ed3f196d469d2669fd4259bc11bce90

Comment: ALTER TABLE res_partner rs 
DROP COLUMN rs.miss_schedule;

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "rs"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE res_partner rs

Comment: You can't use aliases in a DDL statement like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query with no alias

```
ALTER TABLE res_partner DROP COLUMN miss_schedule;
```